# html.hidden for losing value when name attribute is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have an `@html.editorfor` and an `@html.hiddenfor` element in `my.cshtml` view, and on a button click event I'm changing both of the elements' name attributes so that I can post them in a separate list.

The value of the `editorfor` element is supposed to be a string in the model, but the value of the `hiddenfor` element is supposed to be an int.

The problem is that the new list is returning with the right editor value but the hidden value is always returning "0" even though it should be something else. Is there a different way of posting an int value back in a list?

by the way, when I'm posting the values of the elements back without changing their name attributes, everything is posting back correctly.

heres the script that I'm using to change the name attributes:

```
//inside for loop where i is the iteration index
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].EmployeeTimeSeriesDataID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "tsdata_hidden_" + i } })

<script>
 $('somebutton').click(function() {
  var hiddenTsID = "#tsdata_hidden_" + aNumber; //number to match the i from the hidden for
  var nameOfHiddenToDeleteWithIndex = "deleteList[" + deleteIndex + "].EmployeeTimeSeriesDataID";
  //deleteindex starts at 0 and is incremented at the end of every button click, so the new list
  //can be correctly created starting with index[0]

  $(hiddenTsID).attr('name', nameOfHiddenToDeleteWithIndex);
 });
</script>
```

controller action:

```
public ActionResult TimeSeriesData(/*among other params*/EmployeeTimeSeriesData[] deleteList) {
 //working update functionality
 //working add functionality
 foreach (EmployeeTimeSeriesData tsData in deleteList)
  {
   EmployeeTimeSeriesData y = db.EmployeeTimeSeriesData.Find(tsData.EmployeeTimeSeriesDataID); 
   db.EmployeeTimeSeriesData.Remove(y);
  }
  db.SaveChanges();

}
```

Comment: Everything posted back is effectively a string. It is purely down to the server to interpret and convert the values to ints. You need to show your server-side controller action too.

Comment: so maybe do a parseInt on the value first? but I have a breakpoint set and the list's EmployeeTimeSeriesDataID is a string "0" when it should be "1", I'll add the controller action

Comment: Although I do have VS2013, creating a mockup is time-consuming. Can you post a save-as of the HTML from the browser before and after the button is clicked? It may just be an issue in the naming

Comment: You mean view source before and after button click and save them? its a form, wouldn't the form be submitted? also its a div that gets content from ajax, page will refresh after submit and div will be empty again

Comment: Why are you changing the name attribute? `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].EmployeeTimeSeriesDataID` generates the correct name for postback to a collection of `EmployeeTimeSeriesData` (assuming `EmployeeTimeSeriesDataID` is a property of `EmployeeTimeSeriesData`). By perpending `deleteList` to the name attribute, it will no longer bind. The only way that would bind is if `EmployeeTimeSeriesData` contain  a property named `deleteList` which is a collection of an object that contains a property named `EmployeeTimeSeriesDataID`

Comment: I was trying to replace not prepend, because my controller now accepts another parameter called "deleteList"

Answer (score 1):

apparently theres something wrong with the html hiddenfor helper. When I was trying to retrieve the value it was returning blank values, for example:

```
confirm($('tsdata_hidden_0').attr('value'))
```

this was opening up a confirmation box with an empty message, the `'value'` wasn't showing up. Same thing happened when I tried the same thing but with a different attribute (instead of `'value'` I tried `'name'`, `'id'` and they all were blank.)

So then what I did was make a regular html hidden input

```
<input type="hidden" id="someID" name="someName" value="someValue"/>
```

and now when I did

```
confirm($('someID').attr('value'))
```

a confirmation box came up with `"someValue"` as the message, no longer blank. Thank you again, Microsoft, for making life difficult

Answer (score 0):

There might be something wrong with your list binder, try:

```
var nameOfHiddenToDeleteWithIndex =
    "deleteList[" + deleteIndex + "].EmployeeTimeSeriesData.EmployeeTimeSeriesDataID";
```

Comment: I shall try! onward! however, just like to point out that I'm doing the same thing with another field ("value1") so it looks like this var nameOfEditorToDeleteWithIndex = "deleteList[" + deleteIndex + "].Value1"; but this is working??